# Lambda expression error using Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I am doing filtering using some conditions. I used the following condition to check the value. But I get this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.Ienumerable' to 'bool'

Code:

```
var topLocationIds = Model.Where(q => q.JobLocations.Select(c=>c.Locationid))
                                   .GroupBy(c=>c.JobLocations.Select(c=>c.LocationId)))
                                   .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                                   .Take(5)
                                   .Select(g => g.Key).ToList();
```

Why this error? Foreign key table values I can take like wise only..

Comment: what are you trying to check with this conidtion? `Where(q => q.JobLocations.Select(c=>c.Locationid))`

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition should return boolean but it returns integer enumeration with your below code.

`Model.Where(q => q.JobLocations.Select(c=>c.Locationid))`

`Select` is used to project data. In `where`, you should be checking conditions like `q.someid>1`